# CakePHP 3: Display data from join table used in custom finder

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

```
CakePHP Version: 3.1.4
```

I have a custom finder in a model *Paintings* where I join with another table *Artists* and select fields from both to display in a view later:
(They have the relation: *Paintings belongsTo Artists*)

```php
class PaintingsTable extends Table
{
 // top five pics
 public function findTopfive(Query $query, array $options){

    $query
    ->join([
        'artists' =>[
            'table' => 'artists',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'Paintings.artist_id = Artists.id'
        ]
    ])
    ->select(['Paintings.id', 'Paintings.title', 'Paintings.ticket_count', 'Artists.name'])
    ->where(['ticket_count >=' => 1])
    ->order(['ticket_count' => 'DESC'])
    ->limit(5);

    return $query;
}
```

Then I use the finder in a Controller:

```php
class CashpositionsController extends AppController
{
    public function overview()
    {
        // TOP 5 paintings:
        $paintings = TableRegistry::get('Paintings');
        $top_paintings = $paintings->find('topfive');
    }
}
```

I can display the data from the paintings just like this:

```php
<?php foreach ($top_paintings as $paintings): ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?= h($paintings->id); ?> </td>
       <td><?= h($paintings->ticket_count); ?> </td>
       <td> <!-- here should be paintings->artist->name --> </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**But how do I display the Artist.name here that comes from the joined table?**

The data is fetched from the query like this:

```
->top_paintings(array)
  -> 0(object)
     id 9
     title nicepic
     ticket_count 4
     artist_id 80
     -> Artists(array)
         name MrArtist
  -> 1(object)
```

So the data is there but I just cannot get it to display. I tried various approaches with syntax I successfully used in other files but this one I can't figure out. I could not find an example on this in the Cookbook either, but maybe I searched the wrong place.

**What would be the correct syntax do to this?**

Comment: If the table relations are set up correctly, you should be able to skip the join clause in your find and instead use `->contain(['Artists'])`, and your output should be available at `$painting->artist->name`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I used the `->contain(['Artists'])` now instead of the `->join([...])` in the finder function in the model but I still have to `->select` the field like `'this_artist' => Artist.name'`and fetch the data in the view like `$paintings->this_artist`. When I try otherwise like the way you said I get the error "trying to get property of non object" and I see no data in DebugKit. Any idea why? Table relations should all be fine.

Comment: What does your data look like if you eliminate the `select` clause entirely? My understanding is that the benefits of selecting only a few specific fields are extremely minimal, so I generally leave off the `select` and get all the data. Alternately, you might look at using the `autoFields` function in addition to `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, through sheer coincidence I figured it out:

The problem was actually in the query inside the model, where I had to assign a field name to the associated data to access it in the view. I figured it out because I did this example for another model with the predefined SQL-function "count":

```
// top five members
public function findTopfive(Query $query, array $options){

    $query
    ->join([
        'tickets' =>[
            'table' => 'tickets',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'Tickets.member_id = Members.id'
        ]
    ])
    ->join([
        'tickets_paintings' => [
                'table' => 'tickets_paintings',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => ['tickets_paintings.ticket_id = Tickets.id']
        ]
    ])
    ->select([
        'Members.id', 
        'Members.surname',
        'Members.ticket_count', 
        'count' => $query->func()->count('tickets_paintings.painting_id')
    ])
    ->where(['ticket_count >=' => 0])
    ->group('Members.id')
    ->order(['ticket_count' => 'DESC'])
    ->limit(5);

    return $query;
}
```

And I could access the count just like the other fields in the view:

```
<?= h($members->count); ?>
```

**So, to correct the code from my previous question it has to look like:**

```
->select('Paintings.id',....., 'this_artist' => 'Artists.name')
```

And then in the view the field can be accessed just like the others:

```
<?= h($paintings->this_artist); ?>
```

Also the variables from the query displayed in DebugKit will look like this:

```
->top_paintings(array)
  -> 0(object)
     id 9
     title nicepic
     ticket_count 4
     artist_id 80
     this_artist MrArtist
```